# IfExist lying and returning incorrect value

Tags: vbscript

I have `If (fso.FileExists(fso.GetAbsolutePathName("") & "\prefs.txt") = True) Then...` in my VBScript form, I then have it display the path in a message box and I have gone to the path to confirm, but the file I specify does not exist and the statement proves true. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What you get if you put `sTmp = fso.GetAbsolutePathName("") & "\prefs.txt"` and `wscript.echo "sTmp: " & sTmp` then `wscript.echo "FileExists: " & fso.FileExists(sTmp)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it is conceivable that your VBScript installation or your file system is broken, the more probable cause of your problem could be a

> Hidden  2  Hidden file. Attribute is read/write.

attribute on the file:

```
>> WScript.Echo "exists", CStr(goFS.FileExists(".\chmdump.txt"))
>> WScript.Echo goFS.GetFile(".\chmdump.txt").Attributes
>> WScript.Echo goFS.GetFile(".\chmdump.txt").Attributes And 2
>>
exists True
34
2
```

The FSO finds the file, but - depending on settings - file browsers don't:

```
dir chmdump.txt
...
File Not Found

attrib chmdump.txt
A   H      C:\Documents and Settings\eh\chmdump.txt

attrib -H chmdump.txt

dir chmdump.txt
..
13.10.2008  08:48            12.947 chmdump.txt
```